# Setting minimumLineSpacing for UICollectionViewFlowLayout has no effect, must use insetForSectionAtIndex function?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The goal is to define the spacing between sections for a UICollectionView.

However, setting the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as follows with the `minimumLineSpacing` property has no effect:

```
   // Init <collectionView>
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: CollectionViewTopPadding, left: 0, bottom: CollectionViewBottomPadding, right: 0)
    let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
```

The only approach that's working is to use the `insetForSectionAtIndex` as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Other examples on SO set `minimumLineSpacing` so can anyone explain why this code isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple documentation

> The flow layout uses the value in minimumLineSpacing property to set the spacing between lines in a section.

Thus it will not set spacing between the sections, it is for setting space between the rows/columns within the section. If at all you want to achieve spacing between sections without implementing delegate method, you could use `sectionInset` property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Comment: Ahh interesting, yet another reminder to read source documentation instead of what you see on SO

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone is wondering how to only do it for one section:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if section == 0{

       return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0)
    }

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```